# How to Add custom control "abc.ascx" file in Sitefinity 5.3

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-5

I am new to Sitefinity 5.3 I want to create my Usercontrol in Visualstudio 2012 and add that in sitefinitty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the control is exactly the same as implementing it in pure ASP.NET - no difference.

To include it in Sitefinity, you have to register it in the toolbox. Here is the documentation for this: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/adding-controls-to-the-toolbox

Once that's done, you can create a page in Sitefinity and put your custom control on it using drag and drop. Here's a video showing how: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ4VHGKQsrg